# Matplotlib for google stock price example in python data science handbook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

Using the Python data science handbook (pg.198 Fig 3.6 resampling and converting frequencies for anyone from google), I'm trying to follow the example, which is as below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn; seaborn.set()


goog = data.DataReader('GOOG', start='2004', end='2016',
                       data_source='google')

goog = goog['Close']

goog.plot(alpha=0.5, style='-')
goog.resample('BA').mean().plot(style=':')
goog.asfreq('BA').plot(style='--');

plt.legend(['input', 'resample', 'asfreq'],
           loc='upper left');
```

My graph looks like this:
[image: this]

While the example look like this:

[image: book version]

Why is this the case?  I'm pretty certain that the code is an exact duplicate. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: When you do `goog.resample('BA').mean().plot(style=':')` you are reducing your dataset to two dates, that's why it gives you a straight line. Are you sure you want `BA` as your resampling?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel there would seem to be a disconnect between the code and the graph then, that's not what I expected.  I'm currently googling how to define the period, if you know a good resource for this I'd appreciate it

Comment: The period will depend on the underlying data and what do you want to achieve. Perhaps a weekly resampling? Now, with `asfreq` you'll find that you'll have to deal with how to fill missing data. Check their documentations https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong, just that the resampling rule `BA` with `mean()` returns only two points, thus the straight line.

Playing with the different [available offset rules](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) I don't manage to quickly reproduce the desired plot. You should try to explore and use perhaps a multiple of days.

Comment: Excellent that's exactly the resource i need, thanks